# add operation with Kustomize only if not exists

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I want to add a resource limit and request using Kustomize if and only if it's not already configured. Problem is that the deployment is in fact a list of deployments, so I cannot use default values:

values.yaml

```
myDeployments:
  - name: deployment1
  - name: deployment2
    resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 150
          memory: 200
```

kustomize.yaml

```
- target:
      kind: Deployment
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/resources" 
        value:
          limits:
            cpu: 300
            memory: 400
```

Problem here is that it's replaces both deployments' resources, ignoring the resources defined in values.yaml.

Answer (score 4):

You can't make Kustomize conditionally apply a patch based on whether or not the resource limits already exists. You *could* use labels to identify deployments that should receive the default resource limits, e.g. given something like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      metadata:
        labels:
          example.com/default_limits: "true"
[...]
```

You could do something like this in your `kustomization.yaml`:

```
- target:
    kind: Deployment
    labelSelector: example.com/default_limits=true
  patch: |-
    - op: add
      path: "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/resources" 
      value:
        limits:
          cpu: 300
          memory: 400
```

---

However, you could also simply set a default resource limits in your target namespace. See "[Configure Default CPU Requests and Limits for a Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-default-namespace/)" for details. You would create a LimitRange resource in your namespace:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: cpu-limit-range
spec:
  limits:
  - type: container
    default:
      cpu: 150
      memory: 200
```

This would be applied to any containers that don't declare their own resource limits, which is I think the behavior you're looking for.